# How does ConfigurationManager merge or build configurations for a referenced project?

Tags: asp.net, configurationmanager, web.config-transform, system.configuration, web-config

Suppose I have a C# class library project with an `app.config` file and I reference it an ASP.NET project that has a `web.config` file. Suppose I have a key in my `web.config` `AppSettings` called `SmtpServerHostname`. If I need the `SmtpServerHostname` in my referenced class library as well, how should I handle configuring the configuration files? Specifically,

1. If I don't define the `SmtpServerHostname` key in my class library, will that "pass through" because it is being referenced by another project where it is defined?
2. If I do define the key in my class library, which one will take precedence?
3. I currently make use of `web.config` transforms when publishing my application. Is it possible to transform the `app.config` file similarly?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way. There is no merging. In the ASP.NET application, the app.config settings (or library.dll.config) will not be used in any way. You have to set the web.config yourself for the settings you want the ASP.NET application to see.

This is a duplicate, but I'll answer until I or someone else can properly close it as a duplicate.

Comment: Should I delete the question?